# удалить с мемо слова которые есть в txt

Tags: delphi

Есть у меня txt, где много разных слов, которые надо удалить с мемо, если они есть в txt. Например, `она`, `где`, `что` и т.д если будет в txt, удалить с текста мемо1

Comment: и в чем загвоздка?

Answer (score 1):

А в чём проблема? В алгоритме или реализации?

Алгоритмы могут быть как простые (FindReplace), так и более сложные (алгоритм Ахо-Корасика, фильтр Блума, использование хэш таблиц и др.).

В самом простейшем случае что-то вроде

```
Memo1.Text:=StringReplace(Memo1.Text,' она ',' ',[rfReplaceAll , rfIgnoreCase]) ;
```